# Primary Key violation on datetime with differing values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, primary-key

Let's ignore the fact that a `datetime` is being used as a primary key.

Given the following:

```
DECLARE @table table (test datetime primary key)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    test
)
select
    '2015-09-21 00:00:00.001' -- test - datetime
-- successful insert 

INSERT INTO @table
(
    test
)
select
    '2015-09-21 00:00:00.002' -- test - datetime
-- successful insert

INSERT INTO @table
(
    test
)
select
    '2015-09-21 00:00:00.003' -- test - datetime
-- fails due to primary key violation

select * from @table
```

[SQL Fiddle with only first 2 inserts](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/2424)

[SQL Fiddle with all 3 inserts, fails on third insert](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/2425)

What's going on here? All three "attempted" inserted values are distinct, but `.002` and `.003` are being considered "the same value"

Comment: This is a precision issue, as Sean points out in his answer.

Comment: Use `DATETIME2(3)` instead (SQL Server **2008** and newer) and those problems go away

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The datetime datatype does not have that much precision. Try this query to see what happens with those values. The datetime datatype is only precise to .003. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

```
select CAST('2015-09-21 00:00:00.001' as datetime) union all
select '2015-09-21 00:00:00.002' union all
select '2015-09-21 00:00:00.003'
```

Comment: So they're stored with the "entered" precision, but compared for equality by rounding to the nearest .003 millisecond?

Comment: No there is an implicit conversion and the values are rounded to the nearest .003

Answer (score 6):

> datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007
>   seconds, as shown in the following table.

[image]

Source MSDN  [`SQL Server Datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187819.aspx)

Hence your table value `2015-09-21 00:00:00.002` is rounded to `2015-09-21 00:00:00.003` and on your last insert you get the primary key violation.

Datetime is probably one of the worst data types to have you primary key on. Find an alternative column in your table or add a surrogate column to act as a primary key column.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's not considering the milliseconds part differently but if you use `DATETIME2` as datatype then it will succeed since `DATETIME2` will produce a better precision. Try below:

```
DECLARE @table table (test datetime2 primary key)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    test
)
select
    '2015-09-21 00:00:00.001' -- test - datetime
-- successful insert 

INSERT INTO @table
(
    test
)
select
    '2015-09-21 00:00:00.002' -- test - datetime
-- successful insert

INSERT INTO @table
(
    test
)
select
    '2015-09-21 00:00:00.003'
```

Comment: While `datetime2` does have better precision, it could still be a victim to similar behavior. By default precision of `datetime2` is 7 fractional digits, which is 100ns, but the precision can be specified by the user to be between 0 and 7 digits. So rounding can still happen with `datetime2` depending on how the precision is defined for the table column and the precision of the values being inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not unique

Accuracy
Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

Maybe not use datetime as a PK

[datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)